# I have create lib.a file and add some classes ,resource and images.When i use this lib file with header file then it gives exception

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I have create lib.a file and add some classes ,resource and images.When i use this lib file with header file then it gives "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ".
How resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error it seems to me as if you have view controllers in your library and you have created them with the help of interface builder.Wherever you are trying to use your library , those view controller objects are searching for those nib's to to associate with, so now the problem is you can't include nib's in a library , so

1) You either create your views programmaticaly or

2) Ship your xib's as separate files and the other user can include it in his or her project.

and also don't forget to ship images as well.hope this helps.